# Fedora20 is still there despite deleting partition

Tags: windows, multi-boot, windows-8.1, fedora-20

I dual booted fedora20 and windows 8.1 on my PC. Later I deleted the fedora partition and merged it with windows partitions, but still I was getting the fedora option while switching on my system, later I refreshed my pc and that option was gone. But fedora option is still there in BIOS menu. What should I do to remove it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open [Advanced Startup Options](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/windows-8/a/open-advanced-startup-options-windows-8.htm) and run "Startup Repair" or "Command Prompt" and `bootrec /fixmbr`.